# How to replace text with clipboard content in VsCode using VsCodeVim?

Tags: key-bindings, cut-copy-paste, vscode

I am using vscode + vim. Consider a common scenario where I have to yank/delete some text from one place and replace it with some text anywhere else. But as I need to replace I have to first delete the other text. This results into lost of the previously deleted text.

The solution I thought of it that I can map some key to move contents of `"` register to register `a` so it gets saved and whenever I need it I can use `<leader> + p` to paste it. `<leader> + p` is mapped to `"ap`.

I figured out how to move content between registers using `let` but the issue is that vscode vim doesn't support that yet. It is saying

> :let is not implemented yet PRs are welcomed.

Is there any other way I can do this? Is there any alternative for `let` for vscode vim or does anyone have any better solution for this issue.

Comment: Hi Ali, I tempted to provide you a solution. Did it solve your problem? Do you have still open problem after trying the proposed solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution to your use case is to:

1. yank the text you want (using the `y` command)
2. select the text you want to replace in visual mode (e.g.: `viw`,  `vi"` and their friends)
3. past the text you have copied (using the `p` command)

Remark: If you repeat the operation, because the `"` buffer has been changed to the content you have replaced in the first past operation it will lead to a behavior you may not like.

To overcome that problem (of the second replacement) a usual trick, that works on VsCodeVim too, is to map `p` into `pgvy`.

Explanation:

- `p` do the past
- `gv` reselect the pasted text
- `y` restore the `"` register to the pasted content.

Here is the corresponding extract from the VSCode settings: `settings.json` to have it in VsCode:

```
    "vim.visualModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
        {
            "before": ["p"],
            "after": ["p","g","v","y"]
        }
    ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the replace plugin that is available with vscodevim.

use gr[motion] to replace the selection.

e.g: use

> grw

to replace the current word at cursor with the clipboard content.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give more details how to add it because I can't find any replace plugin with vscodevim

Comment: see the settings. or add this settings in settings.json: "vim.replaceWithRegister": true, @MaheerAli